# firefox mv3 background script source URI is not allowed in this document

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm building a browser extension and I want to use mv3 also for firefox, my current problem is that the background script is not working because the generated background page complains about:

`<script> source URI is not allowed in this document: “moz-extension://0f06af60-4e79-4b75-a701-36a83bd8001e/background.js”`

is this a CSP issue? I really don't see what I'm doing wrong :-/

manifest.json

```json
"manifest_version": 3,
"background": {
  "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
},
"content_security_policy": {
  "extension_pages": "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'"
}
```

Comment: It may be a bug in Firefox. Try removing content_security_policy, there should be no need for it.

Comment: unfortunately I only added content_securtiy_policy to the manifest because I got this error :-/

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using `./*.js` inside `web_accessible_resources` because I needed access to some javascript files, firefox didn't like that this also included the background.js file.